# Flat file data source

Tags: birt

i am

very new to Birt

my problem is,

my system generates two files one is contains headers

another one contains  header values 
                                                 columeA               coumnB
now my question is i want to show  data like     header1 ------------> value1
                                                 header2-------------> value2

is it possible through Flat File Data source

Answer (score 1):

yes, its possible. there are different ways but i suggest one of my method that i have applied and is working. 
Steps:
1> create 2 datasource , first for header and second for header values
2> create 2 datasets , first for header & second for header values 
 set header dataset column names as header1 , header2 .. 
 set header_value dataset column names as header1_value , header2_value ..
3> create a Joint Dataset using the previous 2 datasets , connect them with full outer join 
4> drag & drop the joint dataset in designer
5> keep the "header" dataset binding in the header row of the table.
6> keep the "header value" dataset binding in the detail row.

Thats it.

Comment: hi  wizavi  good answer ,but here i want to display  header and header_value as two columns in my table data like    header |  value  like this  Vertical display